# How to copy project's resources folder to output directory in project with a reference to it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2019

I have multiple projects in my solution. One of the projects has resources files (images). Then I have another project with unit tests. I'd like to have all these files available in unit tests project when the project with resources is referenced.

I've tried two solutions:

**a) Apply a post-build script to the project with resources**

The script copies resources directory content to the output (Debug/Release) directory as I need. But the script isn't executed when unit tests project is build (only when the project with resources is)

**b) Set "Copy to Output Directory" property to value "Copy always" to all resources files**

This works as I need even in project that has reference but I have to set this property manually to all the files. I wonder whether there is a way how to manage the same result but with a folder (to automatically copy all its content)

***My question is***: Is there any way how to automatically copy project's resources directory and its content to another project when the project with resources files is referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this link.

https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3203

As the link describes, if files are added to the directory during the build process, you must use a target to expand the wildcard, or it will only copy the files that existed at the start of the build.

You can use the following methods：

Open the *.vcxproj file and add the following code.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <None Include="$(SolutionDir)config\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope it can help you.